# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError

Tags: python, mysql

This is my table :

```
Field   Type       Null  Key  Default  Extra
id      INT(11)     NO   PRI   NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT
name   VARCHAR(50)  NO         NULL
description TEXT    NO         NULL
```

I'm trying to insert data in mysql but when I click submit it gives me:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'name' cannot be null")

Even when I created this table I made the default as none. So, I tried to change the name and description column and I put the default as null and it starts saving in the database but it saves a blank - nothing shown.

Like this:

```
id   name   description
1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you post a query on which it fails?

Comment: yes here you the query
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO todotask(name, description) VALUES(%s, %s)",(name, description))

Comment: Any triggers on the table? Execute this: show triggers like 'todotask'.

Comment: Also, what happens when values are hard coded, for example `"INSERT INTO todotask(name, description) VALUES('string', 'text')"`?

Answer (score 0):

`None` in Python translates to `NULL` on the database side hence the error. Put empty string (`''`) and it should be fine given the DDL you have.